# Bug in python3 code - trying to sum a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, python-3.4

I am learning python3 and I've hit a blocker regarding an exercise I am doing.

Here is the problem I am trying to solve:

"Write a program which repeatedly reads numbers until the user enters "done". Once "done" is entered, print out the total, count, and average of the numbers. If the user enters anything other than a number, detect their mistake using try and except and print an error message and skip to the next number."

Here is my answer:

```
numslist = list()

while True:
    x = input("Enter a number: ")
    numslist.append(x)
    if x is str:
        print ("bad data")
    if x == 'done':
        break

numslistt = numslist[0:-1]

count = 0
for a in numslistt:
    count = count + 1

total = 0
for thing in numslistt:
    total = total + thing

print(numslistt)
print(count)
print(total)
```

I get an error however when trying to add the numbers in the list? Can someone advise on what I am doing wrong?

Here is the Traceback I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 19, in <module>
    total = total + thing
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'
```

Thanks,

Samuel

Comment: Can you describe in more detail what happens when the program runs?

Comment: "I get an error however": it's always good include the error (and its traceback) in your question as well, next to the code causing it.

Comment: `is` tests object identity. It doesn't check if a variable has a special type. BTW, `x` will always be a string.

Comment: Concerning calculating the sum and number of items in a list: Check out the [`sum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum) and [`len`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#len) functions.

Comment: "if x is str": change that to `if isinstance(x, str):`. `x is str` is always `False` here. In fact, it's an unnecessary check, since the output from `input()` always returns a string.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I read inputs as integers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20449427/how-can-i-read-inputs-as-integers)

Comment: I've added the traceback for those that have requested it - should of included it in the first post - sorry!

Comment: Even if you don't use built-in functions for counting the number of list elements and thier sum, you don't need two for-loops for that. You could do both in one.

Answer (score 2):

When you call `input()` you get back a string. You must convert your values to a number using `int()` or `float()` before you can sum them.

The test `x is str` doesn't do what you think: you are testing for `x` to be the actual `str` type, which it isn't. To test whether the value is an instance of `str` use `isinstance(x, str)`.

BTW, you don't need a loop to count the numbers: there's an attribute on the list that will tell you that directly. Also you don't need a loop to sum them, there's a builtin function for that.